# How to avoid lines overlapping?

Tags: reveal.js

Why do i get overlapping lines when trying to use Reveal.js?

The default value is

```
.reveal .slides>section>section {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px 0px;

z-index: 10;
line-height: 1.2em; /* the default value
font-weight: normal;
```

here is the result (cant upload iti here, imghur bug)

http://s24.postimg.org/5rawfbigl/image.jpg

but sadly, i got all the contents get mixed! so i changed the `1.2` to something greater like `2` or `3` to get a normal displaying.

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position absolute doesn't care if there is another element on the targeted area. Try changig to

> position: relative;

Comment: here is the CSS: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/reveal.css#L589

Comment: here is the answer https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/512#issuecomment-20084534